# Apagar as variáveis no fim do método diminui a memória gasta?

Tags: php, memória

Em *php* temos o método `unset` para apagar variáveis da memória, tenho uma dúvida em relação a isso.

Após a execução de um método, as variáveis locais dele já são apagadas automaticamente da memória? Ou é uma boa prática usar o `unset` para apaga-las e liberar um pouco a mémoria?

Segue um exemplo:

```
private function getAllFiles()
{
    $files = (new FinderFiles)->getFiles();

    $progress = ProgressHelper::start($this->output, 'files', count($files));
    $repository = ClassesRepository::instance();

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $repository->pushClass(new AnalyzedClass($file->getRealPath()));
        $progress->advance();
    }
    $progress->finish();
    unset($files, $progress, $repository);
}
```

Com a linha `unset($files, $progress, $repository);` programa consumiria menos memória ou a exclusão dessas variáveis já é feita?

Comment: Apesar de a pergunta que linkei não ser exatamente a mesma, estou considerando que responde sua dúvida. Se não responder, me avise aqui.

Comment: Li a pergunta que você passou, uma frase da primeira resposta deu a dar uma resposta indireta para a minha dúvida.